# How to run an app automatically on reboot for different user?

Tags: rhel, reboot, amazon-ec2, tomcat

I have a ec2 machine/redhat with Tomcat installed. I want only userX to start this app, not ec2-user. However, ec2 automatically boots with ec2-user after restart. How can I make my userX to execture `startup.sh` command automatically. Currently I do it manually by loging with userX, then `bash /opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh`
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create a [systemd service](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) that has `User=userX` in the Service definition. Once it’s enabled, systemd will launch it on boot.

Answer (score 1):

create the file `/etc/systemd/system/whatever.service`

that file contents can be as simple as:

```
[Unit]
Description=<whatever>
After=default.target

[Service]
Type=idle
User=<USERX>
Group=<GROUPX>
ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
TimeoutStartSec=0

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

set ownership and permissions on the custom systemd service file you created

`chown   root.root   /etc/systemd/system/whatever.service`

`chmod   644         /etc/systemd/system/whatever.service`

set ownership and execute permissions on what the service is executing

`chown   USERX.GROUPX   /opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh`

`chmod   750            /opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh`

`sysytemctl daemon-reload`

`systemctl enable whatever.service`

*refer to other poster's link to systemd service description for all the items that can be configured in the custom `whatever.service` file you created; change the name whatever to anything of your liking.*

Comment: I did this, but I am getting this error:Job for tomcat.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status tomcat.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Comment: and here is the detail:  Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-06-26 08:33:57 UTC; 18s ago
  Process: 1670 ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash /opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1670 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)